# Firebase variable based authorization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been using Firebase for one of my games and while it's been an extremely useful service and tool I happened to come across an issue that I didn't address during development which has allowed users to cheat.

As you would expect with Firebase that introduces most of the logic on the client side, I have client-side authorization in place, which was a mistake from the start to begin with. The issue that I'm running into is the following. Please note that this is not my structure, just an example to work from.

```
{
  "user": 
  {
    currently_training: false,
    current_units: 673,
    unit_cap: 1000
  }
}
```

The client would take this and tell the user, "Okay, you're only allowed to train `(1000 - 673) = 327` units. However, by bypassing this on the client side to change the unit_cap to lets say `10,000` the user can now send a request to the database to create `9,327` units, which will result in his units exceeding his unit cap.

How would I go about validating a query, such as..

```
- User requests to train 412 units.
- Insert is not executed as the amount of requested units + current_units > unit_cap
- Error is sent back to client to be handled.

OR

- User requests to train 300 units.
- 300 + current_units <= unit_cap
- Insert executes successfully.

OR

- User requests to train 300 units.
- 300 + current_units <= unit_cap
- currently_training is true, so the Insert fails with error.
```

I'm fairly worried that creating a middleware server is going to be required, which is the reason I went with firebase to begin with. (So I wouldn't have to worry about the scalability of my own servers)

Comment: I am curious how they are changing the 1000 to 10,000? Do your users have direct access to your Firebase console or have the ability to write to the /users node? Are the users authenticating to Firebase at all or is it anonymous? What is 'client-side authentication' in this use case?

Comment: Middleware servers are seldom needed. Even when your security requirements are too complex for [Firebase's database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), you can frequently run the additional validation logic on a back-end server that essentially sits "behind" the same database. See option two in this classic post describing [application architectures for Firebase database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html).